# Efficient operation over grouped dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very big Pandas dataframe where I need an ordering within groups based on another column. I know how to iterate over groups, do an operation on the group and union all those groups back into one dataframe however this is slow and I feel like there is a better way achieve this. Here is the input and what I want out of it. Input:

```
ID   price
1    100.00
1    80.00
1    90.00
2    40.00
2    40.00
2    50.00
```

Output:

```
ID   price  order
1    100.00 3
1    80.00  1
1    90.00  2
2    40.00  1
2    40.00  2 (could be 1, doesn't matter too much)
2    50.00  3
```

Since this is over about 5kk records with around 250,000 IDs efficiency is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rank](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html):

```
df["order"] = df.groupby("ID")["price"].rank(method="first")
df
Out[47]: 
   ID  price  order
0   1  100.0    3.0
1   1   80.0    1.0
2   1   90.0    2.0
3   2   40.0    1.0
4   2   40.0    2.0
5   2   50.0    3.0
```

It takes about 30s on a dataset of 5m rows with 250000 ID's (i5-3330) :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"price": np.random.rand(5000000), "ID": np.random.choice(np.arange(250000), size = 5000000)})
%time df["order"] = df.groupby("ID")["price"].rank(method="first")
Wall time: 36.3 s
```

Answer (score 3):

If speed is what you want, then the following should be pretty good, although it is a bit more complicated as it makes use of complex number sorting in numpy.  This is similar to the approach used (my me) when writing the aggregate-sort method in the package [`numpy-groupies`](https://github.com/ml31415/numpy-groupies).

```
# get global sort order, for sorting by ID then price
full_idx = np.argsort(df['ID'] + 1j*df['price'])

# get min of full_idx for each ID (note that there are multiple ways of doing this)
n_for_id = np.bincount(df['ID'])
first_of_idx = np.cumsum(n_for_id)-n_for_id 

# subtract first_of_idx from full_idx
rank = np.empty(len(df),dtype=int)
rank[full_idx] = arange(len(df)) - first_of_idx[df['ID'][full_idx]]
df['rank'] = rank+1
```

It takes 2s for 5m rows on my machine, which is about 100x faster than using `groupby.rank` from pandas (although I didn't actually run the pandas version with 5m rows because it would take too long; I'm not sure how @ayhan managed to do it in only 30s, perhaps a difference in pandas versions?).

If you do use this, then I recommend testing it thoroughly, as I have not.

Comment: It's likely that @ayhan his solution is sufficient for my use case but I will look into this if it is not, thanks!

Comment: This is in fact much faster than `rank`. It gives the same results by the way. http://i.imgur.com/7UejPRI.png

Comment: Note that this approach assumes that ids are ints >=0, and not excessively large.  If this is not the case some additional work or a slightly different approach is needed (but the general approach will still work).